C# File.Copy vs Access VBA
We have an old MS Access app that, among other things, copies a new MS Access .accdb file to "C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\DB".
Using this VBA code, it copies the .accdb file from a server directory to the users AppData Local folder with no problem.
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.copyfile strRemoteFile, strLocalFile

I rewrote this functionality in a C# console application to test the functionality that will eventually replace our MS Access apps. The C# app can't copy an .accdb anywhere without permission errors...
Console.WriteLine("Removing previous DB copy...");

//find the user local folder
string appPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
appPath = $"{appPath}\\DB Application";

// create folder if does not exits
if (!Directory.Exists(appPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(appPath);
}

// remove copy if exists
if (File.Exists($"{appPath}\\DB.accdb"))
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete($"{appPath}\\DB.accdb");
        Console.WriteLine($"File DB.accdb deleted successfully.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error deleting file: {ex.Message}");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Copying DB to working folder...");
File.Copy(@"\\app18\Database\DB.accdb", appPath);

Console.WriteLine("Launching DB...");
Process.Start($"{appPath}\\DB.accdb");

Environment.Exit(0);

Why can VBA get the job done and C# can't?
Ryan

File.Copy(appPath, @"\\app18\Database\DB.accdb"); is using the folder name not the file name, and the desitination has a double-slash in a verbatim @ string, so it's trying to contact a network server called app18 and share called Database which presumably was not the intenton, also it seems you have got the source and destination backwards. Also use Path.Combine to create paths rather than concatenating yourself.

I fixed the File.Copy code above because I accidentally switched the source and destination. I am trying to get the source file from "app18" server.

Your call to File.Copy looks like it's using a filename (@"\\app18\Database\DB.accdb") and then a directory name (appPath, which you have set to $"{appPath}\\DB Application", which is a folder, right?), but that's not what File.Copy wants. It wants the source filename and destination filename.
What happens if you change File.Copy(@"\\app18\Database\DB.accdb", appPath);  to something like File.Copy(@"\\app18\Database\DB.accdb", $"{appPath}\\DB.accdb");?
